# Does handling an error through an onRejected handler counts as a resolution when chaining promises?

Tags: es6-promise

In a promise chain will a chained promise run if the first promise returns an error that is handled in the error callback?

```
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(
        () => {
            returnError();
        },
        error => {
            logError();
        })
    .then(
        () => {
            willthisRun();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not, the second `.then` will not run `willThisRun()`. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> Once a Promise is fulfilled or rejected, the respective handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) will be called asynchronously (scheduled in the current thread loop). The behavior of the handler function follows a specific set of rules. If a handler function:
>
> - returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value;
> - doesn't return anything, the promise returned by then gets resolved with an undefined value;
> - throws an error, the promise returned by then gets rejected with the thrown error as its value;
> - [...]

The promise returned by the first `.then` will be (quote) "rejected with the thrown error as its value", calling the `onRejected` handler of the second `.then` (which is undefined), which will throw an uncatched exception.

```js
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(
        () => {
            returnError();
        },
        error => {
            // this handler gets called because there is an error
            logError();
        })
    .then(
        // this promise receives the rejection, calling the onrejected argument, which is undefined
        () => {
            willthisRun();
        }
    );
```

Comment: Am i right in thinking if i put:

    .then(() =>  {
            willthisRun();
        }, {
            willthisRun();
        }
    );

will be run because now the method executes in the on resolve portion of the promise as well?

Comment: @AdamWeitzman Yes you could register the same handler for the onRejected and it would be called on rejection.